# Combine minimum values of row and column in matrix

Tags: r, matrix

Suppose I have a vector of size **n=8** `v=(5,8,2,7,9,12,2,1)`. I would like to know how to build a **N x N** matrix that compares every pair of values of v and returns the minimum value of each comparation. In this example, it would be like this:

```
5 5 2 5 5 5 2 1
5 8 2 7 8 8 2 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1
5 7 2 7 7 7 2 1
5 8 2 7 9 9 2 1 
5 8 2 7 9 12 2 1
2 2 2 2 2 2 2 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Could you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`outer(v, v, pmin)`

Notice the use of `pmin`, not `min`, as the former is vectorised but not the latter.